# How to protect android game with points award by time interval from date changing cheating?

Tags: android, algorithm, security

I'm developing an android game that has points. There are some ways to get points and the one of them is to open the game every day. I thought of two ways to implement this but the both have security problems.

### The first way: system date

The app's service gets current system date and checks if bonus was awarded for this date; if it wasn't then award and write this date to the database (suppose this database is encrypted and there is no way to change the data inside it).

**The problem:** cheater can change system date and get points again and again.

**Possible ways of protection:**

1. Fix installation date. If current system date is less that installation date it's a cheater, don't award points. Weakness: cheater can change date to the future not to the past.
2. The same as first but additionally we can check that installation date is greater that app release date (hardcoded, yes). Weakness: first not but growing every day.
3. Check date using the internet. If current system date is less or greater than internet date by more than 24 hours it's a cheater, don't award points. Weakness: cheater can disable the internet.

### The second way: timer

Suppose that we want to make bonus every day at 00:00. When user starts the game first time (suppose at 20:00) calculate how many time left before the bonus time (4 hours). Set timer for this time (4 hours). When the timer goes off award points and start the new one for 24 hours and then similarly.

**The problem:** device can be rebooted and the timer will be destroyed. So after reboot we need to repeat algorithm as the first time: calculate how many time left before the bonus time and start the timer. Cheater can change time to 23:55 and reboot the device and get points; and than do it again and again.

### The third way: timer and database

The same as the second way but additionally timer writes time left to database every minute (for example) and after reboot restore this value.

The problem: I see no weakness but it awards points every 24 hours but not every day.

That's all...

By the way: I've tested the first way of cheating with some games and it works. But some others are protected from this.

I would be happy to hear any ideas or advice. And thanks for your time.

Comment: There’s almost always a server involved. No connection, just store an event to fire later. Coalesce those events on server in case they try anything sneaky.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks, it's an option. No connection - no bonus, why not.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem with database and timer? And 24 hours and a day - what's the difference?

Comment: @NabinBhandari the difference is that "every day" means every day at the same time (for example 00:00) and if the device was turned off for 5 hours timer was turned off too and the cycle is shifting. It's not a big problem but I would like to do it as planed if it's possible.